# Prevent user to close browser / change url during uploading

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http, upload

How can I prevent the user to close the browser / change the url during file uploading. I have create a web app for file uploading, which will upload huge file (1-2GB) and it works fine. except, if user close the browser it just die. How can I show a confirmation box (e.g: Are you sure you want to close the browser) using javascript during uploading?

Comment: There is no way but to put up a message.

Comment: You can't prevent it, all you can do is suggest for the user to not do it with an onbeforeunload warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn it on:

```
window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
```

To turn it off:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Bear in mind that this isn't a normal event - you can't bind to it in the standard way.

Comment: Please note that, when you close the browser it will warn user and if user choose to leave page, it will close/redirect the page and you upload process will die

Comment: @Amit which can't be prevented without replacing the browser entirely.

Answer (score 1):

define a custom function for the 'onbeforeunload' event.

```
var window.onbeforeunload = function(){ alert('window is closing'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'custom message go here';
    });
```

Comment: jQuery isn't really needed.  No need for the extra dependency.